# How to enable loading local data on client sides with powershell?

Tags: mysql, powershell, csv, import

I'm trying to insert data via a CSV file to a MySQL Table over PowerShell.

```
$SQL="Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=theServer;Database=import;UID=Monty;PWD=some_Password;AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;"

$WEBDBConnection=New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection

$WEBDBConnection.ConnectionString=$SQL

$WEBDBConnection.Open()

$WEBDBCommand=New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand

$WEBDBCommand.Connection=$WEBDBConnection

$WEBDBCommand.CommandText="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Test.csv' INTO TABLE import LINES TERMINATED BY ';';"

$WEBDBCommand.ExecuteReader()

$WEBDBConnection.Close()
```

Executing the Script I'll get an error that 'loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides'

On the Server side I activated 'local_infile' and I thought adding 'AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;' to the connection should activate it on the client side. So I don't get why I get this error message. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Connor

Comment: Try `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `ExecuteReader()`

Comment: Didn't work, same error as before